# SQL Server full log issue -- how to update the database?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I am working with SQL Server 2000, and trying to change the data type of a field from varchar to nvarchar, so that it can handle international characters.  However, there is already a lot of data in that table, and when I try to save the change, I get the following error:

Unable to modify table. 
ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The log file for database 'AppTest_Apps' is full. Back up the transaction log for the database to free up some log space.

This is a one-time update -- how do I get around the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to allow the log file to grow larger (see the options on the log file), or backup and shrink it.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272318

Answer (score 1):

Try running a transaction loop that commits every n number of records. So could rename the current table from X to Y. You can do this with this command sp_RENAME '[OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]'.

Recreate the X with the new datatype column set and then batch insert from Y back into X committing every loop.  By inserting with transaction batch you can keep your log growth under control by committing every n number of records inserted.

Pseudo code

```
Get @max_id from Y int @max_id 
Get min_id from Y into @current_value
Loop until @current_value <= @max_id

BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Y
FROM X
WHERE seq_id >= @current_value and less than @batchsize + @current_value
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Or do like KiwiNige says. If you have the disk space increase the log for this one time event and resize it back down after. That would be the easiest as far as taking less thought. But if your disk space is an issue the batch loop insert will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I see two ways:

1. Just backup the transaction log. Something like BACKUP LOG dbanme TO DISK='c:\dblog.bak'
2. bring your database into SIMPLE recovery mode (e.g., in Enterprise Manager: database-> options -> recovery model, select Simple)